# Save results of a python function into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi folks good afternoon - I am running into an issue, and it is a simple issue, however I am having some issues in base python (3.7) 
Problem: So I am trying to create this loop, that just finds divisors for an integer and then I would like to save the result as an index able object (e.g a list) but when I run the following code my object labeled "test" is an empty list

```
# function divisors
def divisors(n):
#empty list start
    test = []
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if (n % i == 0):
        print(i),
        #append test
        test.append(i), # I know i is not the correct object here, it's just a place holder for this example
    i = i + 1
```

could you please point to me what mistake I am making here? I can solve this problem using numpy, but I would like to understand python and how it works better. Seems like I have to add a variable that stores the results for loop and then append test with that variable?

thank you much

Comment: You set `i += 1` on the way out of the function...  This is not going to be useful.

Comment: Thank you Stephen - I will give it a try. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the list as an argument:

```
def divisors(test):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if (n % i == 0):
            print(i)
        #append in test
        test.append(i), # I know i is not the correct object here, it's just a place holder for this example
        i = i + 1

a = []
divisors(a)
```

Or return your list:

```
def divisors():
    test = []
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if (n % i == 0):
            print(i)
        #append in test
        test.append(i), # I know i is not the correct object here, it's just a place holder for this example
        i = i + 1
    return test

a = divisors()
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek and Zaven. I will give it a go. I appreciate your help.